# How to make a json call from the codeigniter database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to search with Ajax, but my data is in json. I will search by book title, but something went wrong. I use JSON_EXTRACT, but I get an error. What do you think I might have done wrong?

```php
    public function kitapara($search)
    {
        $this->db->select("*, JSON_EXTRACT(kitap_json, '$.kitap_ad') AS kitapad");
        $this->db->like('kitapad', $search);
        $this->db->limit(8);
        $query = $this->db->get('kitaplar');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

[image: database]

**The Error I Received**

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'kitapad' in 'where clause'

SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(kitap_json, '$.kitap_ad') AS kitapad FROM `kitaplar` WHERE `kitapad` LIKE '%deneme%' ESCAPE '!' LIMIT 8

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/kitapsepet/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: 'kitapad' is not a column in the table. It's not in the table you posted either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column alias you specified `kitapad` might not working with where clause, Try column name instead as.

```
$this->db->like('kitap_json', $search);
```